# Show custom message before running SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

Is there a way to ask confirmation from the user before running an SSRS report? Something like: Are you sure you want to run this report? Yes No. Then, run the report based on the answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, the only thing you can do is create a "required" parameter and force the user to select or enter the parameter.  When you run the report you will see a parameter at the top and notice that the report does not appear until after you have selected the parameter.  For this parameter, you can simply add one value "Yes".